# How to access the first element of a tuple in a list?

Tags: f#

I am trying to make a collision method in a class in f#. 
The collision method should have one input which is time. 
The method should check a number of drones that should be moving with time and whether some of them will collide. A collision is defined as being within 5 "blocks" of each other.

I have so far this code for the method.

```
type Airspace(drones:Drone list) = 
    let mutable drones = drones
        member x.Drones with get() = drones
    member x.Collision(time:int) =
        for d = 1 to time do 
           for i = 1 to drones.Length do
               for j = 1 to drones.Length do
                   if drones.Item(i).Position.Item1 - drones.Item(j).Position.Item1 >= -5.0 || drones.Item(i).Position.Item1 - drones.Item(j).Position.Item1 <= 5.0 
                   then if drones.Item(i).isFinished() = True && drones.Item(j).isFinished() = True then printfn "Drone: %A will collide with %A" (drones.Item(i)) (drones.Item(j))
```

By the way drones is a list of Drones and a drone has a current position as a tuple float*float, a destination also as a float*float and speed which is a float.

I am pretty sure this is wrong

```
drones.Item(i).Position.Item1
```

But I am not sure how I can access the first i'th element in a list and then take only the first element of the tuple and compare it with another one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not 100% wrong, it might work but yes, the recommendation is not to use `ItemX` and instead to pattern match the tuple elements, so you can do this:

```
let (xi, _) = drones.Item(i).Position
let (xj, _) = drones.Item(j).Position
if xi - xj >= -5.0 || xi - xj <= 5.0
```

Btw, if you don't really need to use the index you can also change the loops to:

```
       for di in drones do
           for dj in drones do
               let (xi, _) = di.Position
               let (xj, _) = dj.Position
```

Also note that you can use the function `List.allPairs` piped to `List.tryFind` instead of for loops.